# Mongodb nested array group with key value array count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have mongodb structure like below:

```
{
"_id":"123456789",
"name":"item name 1",
"variants":[
    {
    "size":"150 ml",
    "filters":[

    {"name":"filter 1",
    "value":"value 1"},
    {"name":"filter 2",
     "value":"value 2"}
  ]
   } 
]
},

{
"_id":"987654321",
"name":"item name 1",
"variants":[
    {
    "size":"200 ml",
    "filters":[

    {"name":"filter 1",
    "value":"value 2"},
    {"name":"filter 2",
     "value":"value 1"}
  ]
   } 
]
}
```

Now i want count of filter with group by name and value.
i.e.

```
[{filter 1:[{value:value 1, count:10}, {value: value 2, count:5}]},
{filter 2:[{value:value 1, count:5}, {value: value 2, count:2}]}
```

or

```
  [{name:filter 1, value:value 1, count:10}, {name:filter 1, value:value 2, 
count:5}]
```

how to achieve this using mongodb aggregrate and group query?

Comment: See this [Aggregation $group example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/), which has group by multiple fields (like your problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this Way:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$variants" },
    { $unwind: "$variants.filters" },
    { $group:
        {
            _id: "$variants.filters",
            count:{$sum:1}
        }
    },
    { $addFields: {"name" : "$_id.name", "value" : "$_id.value"}},
    { $project: {_id: 0} }
]);
```

A working example at https://mongoplayground.net/p/an2xVfDusJn.

Comment: The last stage `{ $project: {_id: 0} }` can be removed and the `_id: 0` can be projected in the `addFields` stage itself..

Comment: @prasad_, it is 0.0 in this case if i put _id:0 at addfields level.

Comment: @MihirShah You are right. Replace `$addFields` and `$project` with this: `{ $project: { name : "$_id.name", value : "$_id.value", count: 1, _id: 0 } }`.

Comment: @MihirShah Having extra stages can be sometimes a performance problem, especially if number of documents are large. So, its a just a good practice to avoid those always.